# How to bind to a privileged port from a non-root process, on a Synology NAS

Tags: root, busybox, bind, nas, synology

I want to run a custom DNS server ([NxFilter](http://www.nxfilter.org/p2/) to be precise) on a [Synology DS115j NAS](https://www.synology.com/en-global/products/DS115j), which of course binds on port 53. This works when running as root, but I want to lock down the process now.

This NAS runs a busybox flavor of linux (using DSM5 in Synology parlance). I have installed Java with the Java Manager Package. Now, I look for a way to run the java process under a non-root account, while still allowing it to bind to the privileged Port 53.

I have looked into this great answer: https://superuser.com/questions/710253/allow-non-root-process-to-bind-to-port-80-and-443 but this does not work on my Synology box. I neither have `setcap` nor `authbind` available.

So the question is: **How to specifically allow a process/binary to bind to a privileged port on a busybox linux?**

Answer (score 2):

Do you have access to iptables, I vaguely remember that the Synology NAS boxes do? If so you can put a redirect in with this:-

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 7000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-port 7000
```

Line 1 adds an opening to port 53
Line 2 adds an opening to port 7000 which is what you should set your java app to use
Line 3 adds a redirect that any traffic inbound on port 53 gets directed to port 7000.